# jQuery keyup function not working in chrome without an alert

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery keyup code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".faq_question .question").keyup(function(e){
        if((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 13){   
            $(this).trigger("click");
        }
    });
});
```

when i place an alert after document.ready handler the script is working as expected. Without the alert the script is not working. What might be the issue. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: could you please paste your html code also.

Comment: Note that `e` is being used, but hasn't been defined (at least, within the snippet). So, you likely have ReferenceErrors.

Comment: Not to mention that you're missing a `)` before the `;` at the end.

Comment: I have edited the question. Missed the bracket and 'e'. Now added..

Comment: No the content is already present in the DOM. It is not inserted into the page via ajax.

Comment: It works fine in IE.

Comment: what about very first comment .. please include html of problem

Comment: The HTML is something as follows:   <div class="faq_container">
  
 <div class="faq_container_vis private" id="general_questions">
  <br>
  <h1><u>General Program Questions</u></h1>
  <br>
  <div class="question" tabindex="1" title="What is the time now?">What is the time now?</div>
  <div class="answer" tabindex="1" style="display: none;">
   <strong>Answer:</strong>
   The time is 12:45 pm.    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: is your div is editable??

Comment: No it is not editable.

Comment: It is just a FAQ page which toggles the answer div when clicked question div

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the issue, but at the end you are missing closing bracket to end the **ready** function

Comment: Thank you. I have missed it. Now i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

`$(".faq_question .question").keypress(function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) {
            $(this).click();
            return false;
        }
    });`

As commented above your `e` is not defined please try it this way.

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="text" id="faq" name="faq" /><span id="ms"></span>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#faq").keyup(function (e) {
        $('#ms').append('pressed');
        var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (keycode == '13') {

            alert('clicked');

        }

    });
});
```

This one worked for me. Just try.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxfxdfk0/)